# Cómo tomar desde el frontend un JSON creado en el servidor por java?

Tags: java, json

Tengo esta clase de java con varios end-points, uno realiza insercciones a la base de datos y el otro consultas, los cuales funcionan excelentes a la vez crean un archivo JSON c/u, acá viene mi inconveniente, no acostumbro a usar nunca Javascript para nada, intento abocarme al backend, sin embargo tengo que hacer un servicio Rest para un curso que estoy haciendo y no sé cómo enganchar desde el frontend el archivo que mi servidor produjo en el back end. Intenté copiar y amoldar algo que encontré por la web en un archivo .js sin embargo no funciona. Me podrían orientar para poder avanzar un poco? porque sí o sí tengo que tomar datos desde frontend.

```
package org.comunidadIT.proyecto.controladores;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;

import org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.AutenticarUsuario;
import org.comunidadIT.proyecto.accesoDatos.ConexionAeropuerto;
import org.comunidadIT.proyecto.entidades.Administrador;
import org.comunidadIT.proyecto.entidades.Empleado;

import com.google.gson.Gson;


@Path("/administradores")
public class Administradores {

String numerosLetras= new String("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+");
String soloLetras= new String("[^a-zA-Z]+");
String soloEmail= new String("[^a-zA-Z0-9@._-]");

//Al final están los métodos Response declarados.
//Inserta administrador en mysql table 'administradores' y genera un dato JSON en texto o archivo
@POST
@Path("/addAdministrador")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String insertarAdministrador(@FormParam("nombre") String nombre , @FormParam("apellido") String apellido, @FormParam("usuario") String usuario, @FormParam("pass") String pass, @FormParam("email") String email, @FormParam("direccion") String direccion){


    try
        {
        //Probamos conectarnos
        ConexionAeropuerto c= new ConexionAeropuerto();
        Connection con= c.connectarAhora();

        //Si la conexión no es nula entonces realizar dos consultaa de insercción de datos y creación de tabla
        if(con!=null)
                {
                    Statement st;
                    st=con.createStatement();
                    st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO administradores(nombre,apellido,usuario,pass,email,direccion) VALUES('"+nombre.trim().replaceAll(soloLetras, "")+"','"+apellido.trim().replaceAll(soloLetras, "")+"','"+usuario.trim().replaceAll(numerosLetras, "")+"','"+pass.trim().replaceAll(numerosLetras, "")+"','"+email.trim().replaceAll(soloEmail, "")+"','"+direccion.trim().replaceAll(numerosLetras, "")+"')");
                    st.close();
                    System.out.println("Funciona el try and catch, los deberían haberse ingresado a la DB 'administradores'");

                    Statement createSt;
                    createSt=con.createStatement();
                    createSt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS empleados_"+usuario+"(personaId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, nombre text(11) NOT NULL, apellido text(11) NOT NULL, direccion text(20) NOT NULL, cargo text(20) NOT NULL, sueldo_cargo float NOT NULL, cargas_sociales float NOT NULL, vacaciones float NOT NULL, sueldo_neto float NOT NULL)");
                    createSt.close();

                    System.out.println("Funciona el try and catch y debería haberse creado una tabla nueva");
                    MetodosResponse.CREADO();   //ResponseBuilder 200
                } 
        else
                {
                    System.out.println("Algo Salió mal no se pudo insertar los datos");
                    MetodosResponse.UNAUTHORIZED(); //ResponseBuilder 401
                    return "Algo Salió mal no se pudo insertar los datos";
                }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) 

                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    //Creamos la lista y le ponemos las variables que a su vez están conectadas al construcctor de la Case Empleados
    List<Administrador> lista= new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add(new Administrador(nombre.trim().replaceAll(soloLetras, ""), apellido.trim().replaceAll(soloLetras, ""), usuario.trim().replaceAll(numerosLetras, ""), pass.trim().replaceAll(numerosLetras, ""), email.trim().replaceAll(soloEmail, ""), direccion.trim().replaceAll(numerosLetras, "") ));

            //Creamos un object Gson() que nos permite usar el toJson()
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            //Creamos un String y al mismo le aplicamos el toJson(objeto list)
            String JsonToString= gson.toJson(lista);

            //Retornamos el String anterior
            return JsonToString;
    }


//Consulta de todos los administradores de la DB
@GET
@Path("/consultaAdministrador")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String loginAdministrador(@QueryParam("usuario") String usuario, @QueryParam("pass") String pass){

    //Este grupo de variables transforman a JSON y con el while de abajo itera a todos los elementos del ArrayList
    Gson gson= new Gson();
    List<Administrador> listado= new ArrayList<>();
    String stringJson= gson.toJson(listado);


    try
        {

        ConexionAeropuerto c= new ConexionAeropuerto();
        Connection con= c.connectarAhora();

        if(con!=null && usuario.equals("admin") && pass.equals("admin"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Funciona el try and catch");

                    String sql="select * from administradores";

                    Statement st= con.createStatement();

                    ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(sql);


                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                        String nombre= rs.getString("nombre");
                        String apellido= rs.getString("apellido");
                        String usuario1= rs.getString("usuario");
                        String pass1= rs.getString("pass");
                        String email= rs.getString("email");
                        String direccion= rs.getString("direccion");

                        //Esta línea es sólo demostrativa de que funcionan las variables que toman datos de la DB
                        System.out.println(nombre+" "+apellido+" "+usuario1+" "+pass1+" "+email+" "+direccion);

                        //Adherimos a la lista una fila nueva con una columna nueva.
                        listado.add(new Administrador(nombre,apellido,usuario1,pass1,email,direccion));

                        //Actualizamos el String del Json sin crearlo nuevamente.
                        stringJson= gson.toJson(listado);

                        MetodosResponse.ACCEPTED(); //ResponseBuilder 200
                    }

                } 
        else
                {
                    System.out.println("Algo Salió mal no se pueden ver los datos o no tiene acceso a ellos");
                    MetodosResponse.UNAUTHORIZED(); //ResponseBuilder 401
                    return "Algo Salió mal no se pueden ver los datos o no tiene acceso a ellos";
                }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 

                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    return stringJson;
    }

}
```

Y este es mi archivo .js que lo completé buscando ejemplos de la internet, sin embargo no sé si es el que necesito o si está todo mal, tenía una variable llamada parametros, pero se la saqué porque por lo que entiendo los parámetros ya los estoy invocando desde el servidor con @FormParam, y sin la existencia de este archivo js los datos se insertan igual y el JSON se genera bien desde el servidor. Por eso a send() le puse null.
Hay algún error en la ruta del endpoint?

```
function textoDinamico(){

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost:8091/Proyecto_Final_AAB/rest/administradores/addAdministrador";

http.open("POST", url, true);

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(null);
}
```

Este es el archivo html:

```
<h1>Registro de usuarios Administradores de Aeropuertos.</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="div1">

    <form action="http://localhost:8091/Proyecto_Final_AAB/rest/administradores/addAdministrador" method="post" >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>    
                    <label id="labelNombre" name="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="inputNombre" name="nombre" type="text"><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>    
                    <label id="labelApellido" name="apellido">Apellido:</label>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="inputApellido" name="apellido" type="text"><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <!--  
            <tr>
                <td>    
                    <label name="genero">Género:</label>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input name="genero" type="text"><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        --> 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label id="labelUsuario" name="usuario">Usuario:</label>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="inputUsuario" name="usuario" type="text"><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label id="labelPass" name="pass">Pass:</label>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="inputPass" name="pass" type="text"><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>    
                    <label id="labelEmail" name="email">E-mail:</label>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="inputEmail" name="email" type="text"><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>    
                    <label id="labelDireccion" name="direccion">Direccion:</label>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="inputDireccion" name="direccion" type="text"><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="textoDinamico()">

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </div>

    <div id="div2">

        <ul id="ul1"></ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza  Si podés me tirás una explicación o dónde mirar? esto de querer usar el JSPN  del backend desde el front end me está complicando la existencia.

Comment: Te recomiendo que utilices una librería (por ejemplo JQuery) para hacer las llamadas AJAX (o XHR) de forma mucho más sencilla; puedes [leer aquí](http://librosweb.es/libro/fundamentos_jquery/capitulo_7/metodos_ajax_de_jquery.html) sobre esto.

Comment: Está bien lo entiendo, pretendía hacerlo sin jquery pero veo que no hay otra forma, sin embargo se puede eso que estoy intentando hacer? tomar un JSON ya producido del lado del servidor? porque veo pocos ejemplos. me manejo mejor en el backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno al final solucioné el inconveniente, que por lo visto fue no utilizar ajax para el envío de datos. ahora voy a volver a copiar los archivos modificados y andando muy bien. Borré el submit y el form  y dejé el onclick(). De esta manera el envio de datos xmlhttprequest anda mucho mejor y se puede manipular la respuesta, que ése era mi problema inicial.

Este es el archivo html.

```
<h1>Registro de usuarios Administradores de Aeropuertos.</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="div1">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>    
                    <label id="lnombre" name="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text"><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>    
                    <label id="lapellido" name="apellido">Apellido:</label>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="apellido" name="apellido" type="text"><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label id="lusuario" name="usuario">Usuario:</label>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="usuario" name="usuario" type="text"><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label id="lpass" name="pass">Pass:</label>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="pass" name="pass" type="text"><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>    
                    <label id="lemail" name="email">E-mail:</label>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text"><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>    
                    <label id="ldireccion" name="direccion">Direccion:</label>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="direccion" name="direccion" type="text"><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="regAdminReq()">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="div2">

        <ul id="ul1"></ul>

    </div>
```

Este es el archivo javascript que recibe la orden de utilizar una de sus funciones cuando tocan el boton por medio del onclick:

```
function regAdminReq(){

var nombre= document.getElementById("nombre").value;
var apellido= document.getElementById("apellido").value;
var usuario= document.getElementById("usuario").value;
var pass= document.getElementById("pass").value;
var email= document.getElementById("email").value;
var direccion= document.getElementById("direccion").value;

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost:8091/Proyecto_Final_AAB/rest/administradores/addAdministrador";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    alert(xmlhttp.status);

    var tagElegido= document.getElementById("div2");
    var newul= document.createElement("ul");
    tagElegido.appendChild(newul);

    var datos= xmlhttp.responseText;

    newul.innerHTML="Los datos fueron ingresados con éxito para realizar insercciones a su base de datos ingrese a: <br> <a href= 'insertarEmpleado.jsp'>Insertar Empleados</a>";


    }
};

xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("nombre="+nombre+"&apellido="+apellido+"&usuario="+usuario+"&pass="+pass+"&email="+email+"&direccion="+direccion);
}
```

Para que javascript pueda encontrar bien los input tags tienen que estar declarados en el archivo html con su id, asi podemos usar el getElementById("input").value, y para que la insercción de datos sea exitosa los nombres "intuyo" debería ser iguales que los declarados en el header con cada uno de sus @FormParam como parámetros del endpoint a donde la función javascript tiene declarada la ruta.

```
@POST
@Path("/addAdministrador")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String insertarAdministrador(@FormParam("nombre") String nombre , @FormParam("apellido") String apellido, @FormParam("usuario") String usuario, @FormParam("pass") String pass, @FormParam("email") String email, @FormParam("direccion") String direccion){


    try
        {
        //Probamos conectarnos
        ConexionAeropuerto c= new ConexionAeropuerto();
        Connection con= c.connectarAhora();

        //Si la conexión no es nula entonces realizar dos consultaa de insercción de datos y creación de tabla
        if(con!=null)
                {
                    Statement st;
                    st=con.createStatement();
                    st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO administradores(nombre,apellido,usuario,pass,email,direccion) VALUES('"+nombre.trim().replaceAll(soloLetras, "")+"','"+apellido.trim().replaceAll(soloLetras, "")+"','"+usuario.trim().replaceAll(numerosLetras, "")+"','"+pass.trim().replaceAll(numerosLetras, "")+"','"+email.trim().replaceAll(soloEmail, "")+"','"+direccion.trim().replaceAll(numerosLetras, "")+"')");
                    st.close();
                    System.out.println("Funciona el try and catch, los deberían haberse ingresado a la DB 'administradores'");

                    Statement createSt;
                    createSt=con.createStatement();
                    createSt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS empleados_"+usuario+"(personaId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, nombre text(11) NOT NULL, apellido text(11) NOT NULL, direccion text(20) NOT NULL, cargo text(20) NOT NULL, sueldo_cargo float NOT NULL, cargas_sociales float NOT NULL, vacaciones float NOT NULL, sueldo_neto float NOT NULL)");
                    createSt.close();

                    System.out.println("Funciona el try and catch y debería haberse creado una tabla nueva");


                } 
        else
                {
                    System.out.println("Algo Salió mal no se pudo insertar los datos");
                    return "Algo Salió mal no se pudo insertar los datos";
                }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) 

                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


    //Creamos la lista y le ponemos las variables que a su vez están conectadas al construcctor de la Case Empleados
    List<Administrador> lista= new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add(new Administrador(nombre.trim().replaceAll(soloLetras, ""), apellido.trim().replaceAll(soloLetras, ""), usuario.trim().replaceAll(numerosLetras, ""), pass.trim().replaceAll(numerosLetras, ""), email.trim().replaceAll(soloEmail, ""), direccion.trim().replaceAll(numerosLetras, "") ));

            //Creamos un object Gson() que nos permite usar el toJson()
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            //Creamos un String y al mismo le aplicamos el toJson(objeto list)
            String JsonToString= gson.toJson(lista);

            //Retornamos el String anterior
            return JsonToString;
    }
```

Es muy importante que en el endpoint si es "post" que lleve esta linea en el header: "@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)"
También tener en cuenta que la función javascript tiene que tener si o si antes de esta linea nombreDelObjetoXMLHttp.send("parametros") la siguiente: nombreDelObjetoXMLHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  Me imagino que la razón es porque es línea le debe decir que léa si el endpoint tiene parámetros, ya que cuando no la colocaba la insercción de datos no se realizaba. Bueno intenté responderme mi propia pregunta y espero que a alguien le de una mano. abrazos